# Android Expandable Listview have header and child from different table

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In one of my app i have database table like

```
Table 1 :Menu
```

column

ID,
MenuName,
MeuID

and `Table 2 Menuproduct`
column

menuId,
menuprice

I need it like

i header of expandble list
menu name
and in child price. like that

how to make it possible? as i have to pass MenuId to get menu price
Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **join** query to get the detail from sqlite database
If you want the details based on MenuID then your query will be like following

```
SELECT Menu.MenuID, Menu.MenuName, menuprice 
FROM Menu 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Menuproduct ON Menu.MenuID = Menuproduct.menuId;
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm
you need to store the result as custom object in array list.Checkout following

[exapandible listview](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

Comment: i know but how to fill them in exp list?

Comment: I have edited my answer. you need to store the result as custom object in array list. check the link I have added

Comment: every time last data filles in child